# Understanding Red/System compilation optimizations compared to GCC

Tags: elf, red

While reading the [Red site](http://www.red-lang.org/2011/03/having-fun-with-redsystem.html), I came across a statement stating that compiling an hello world Red/System program creates..

> "...a 162 bytes ELF binary, while a similar C code would
>   produce a 5-6KB binary using Gcc"

That's amazing. Can someone explain/point me to the techniques making such optimizations possible?

Comment: I don't know the official answer, but what I do know I know from [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was achieved by having an almost empty runtime library (just a few syscalls wrappers) and an ELF emitter which would not align sections on 4K page boundaries for optimal loading.

Though, that was true for Red/System [0.1.0](https://github.com/red/red/releases/tag/v0.1.0), so in its very early days, not true anymore (now it would be similar to other compilers). Though we still have a `-r` compilation option for compiling Red/System code without any runtime, but as nobody uses it, it might not work anymore (should be easy to fix anyway if someone needs it, just drop by Red's [chat](http://gitter.im/red/red) and ask for it. ;-))